# Access a link from Java

Tags: java, vps

Today I rented a VPS and I managed to move entire my website on it, but now I have some problems. I try to access an XML from java (I have an Android app) to get some exchange rates from my website.

If I use `www.myDomain.com/ecbrates.xml`,it's not working.

I get error `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL`.

It works only if I use `www.vpsIP/ecbrates.xml`. Do you have any ideas why it makes problems?

Comment: make sure you have mapped your domain name to the IP assigned to you by your VPS provider.  Also, check that the DNS records are updated to reflect this.  Your VPS should have a help section on how to use your VPS with your own domain name.

Comment: "HTTP response code: 403 for URL" means "FORBIDDEN", ACCESS DENIED.  In other words, it's a web server configuration issue.

Comment: Q: Can you "ping" by hostname and by IP address?  Is the IP address correct when you ping by hostname?  Q: What kind of web server does the VPS provide?  Apache?  Q: If Apache, have you looked at the error logs, and at httpd.conf?  Q: Does your VPS provide any support or on-line help?  Again - I believe the problem is with server-side (web and or network) configuration, and *NOT* with your Java code.  IMHO...

Comment: I don't now very much about how to set up a VPS but if i access mydomain from a browser it will redirect me on my website. I will write an email to the support departament, maybe they can guide me to a help page because I did not find information.. The vps is bought from ovh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen that my previous post has been deleted... Fine..

Finally I believe I found the answer, the problem is that I have dns from cloudflare and they do not allow to access your domain from outside of browsers. I guess it's a security thing...